# wxpython bitmap adding textctrl/combobox top of it?

Tags: python, bitmap, wxpython

I was trying to find if its possible to add textctrl/combobox top of GenStaticBitmap in wxpython.

Did not find anything with the fast searches i did. Its not first in the priorities, but i feel like it would make the program usage better.

In this case i have screenshot taken from webpage and user can select inputbox and it should be textctrl over the bitmap positioned where it was selected. (i have it working already with textctrl positioned elsewhere).

```
# example something like this
self.staticbitmap = GenStaticBitmap(self.panel, self.bitmap)
text = wx.textctrl(self.panel)
# Have sizer position it here?
```

I can not give full code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you searching for something like a background bitmap (controls on top of a user-defined bitmap)?

[Mike Driscoll has described a solution for this in his Blog.](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/18/wxpython-putting-a-background-image-on-a-panel/)

Comment: Yes.

Link does give me information to start digging deeper and is what i was looking for. There are some complications like position/delete during run as well as there is already some controls on bitmap.  

Thnx for the link.